# Unhandled exception at 0x0010D9DB in MyProgram.exe: 0xC000001D: Illegal Instruction

Tags: assembly, x86

I get an exception at the end of the program and I do not know to fix it. After I enter the size of the loop, and enter the numbers, it outputs everything without any errors, but after it outputs the result, it throws an exception and I don’t have any idea why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    
    char howManyNums[] = "How many numbers: ";
    char firstInput[] = "%d";
    int i = 0;

    char msgEnterNumb[] = "Enter a number: ";
    char secondInput[] = "%d";
    int n = 0;

    char pos[] = "Positive: %d\n";
    int posNum = 0;

    char neg[] = "Negative: %d\n";
    int negNum = 0;
    
    char zer[] = "Zero:     %d";
    int zeroNum = 0;

        
    _asm {
        
        // Size of loop 
        lea eax, howManyNums
        push eax
        call printf
        lea eax, i
        push eax
        lea eax, firstInput
        push eax
        call scanf
        add esp, 8 

        // Set up the Loop
        mov ecx, i
        floop:
        push ecx

        // Enter number: 
        lea eax, msgEnterNumb
        push eax
        call printf
        lea eax, n
        push eax
        lea eax, secondInput
        push eax
        call scanf

        // Check if it's positive,negative or zero
        mov eax, n
        cmp eax, 0

        jg positive
        je zero
        jmp negative

        positive:
        inc posNum
        jmp endif

        negative:
        inc negNum
        jmp endif

        zero:
        inc zeroNum
        jmp endif

        endif:

        // Ending the loop
        add esp, 8 
        pop eax
        pop ecx
        loop floop

        // Print how many pos, neg and zero nums
        // Positives
        push posNum
        lea eax, pos
        push eax
        call printf
        add esp, 8

        // Negatives
        push negNum
        lea eax, neg
        push eax
        call printf
        add esp, 8
        // Zeros

        push zeroNum
        lea eax, zer
        push eax
        call printf
        add esp, 8
    }
}
```

Comment: After some of the calls, you adjust the stack pointer to remove the parameters from the stack, but you don’t do it after every call. So at the end, the stack pointer isn’t the same as at the start.

Comment: what is the error message? i am not sure if changing the esp register is correct.

Comment: 0x0010D9DB its pointing to the EIP register, i've tried with poping and pushing registers and variables but again it does not work